# I Created a function which is Async Function, but it is showing me underfine function, please aid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I create some function which are async base the first function get called and is okay but the remaining subsequent question is not refered to within the App.js component. And within my console, I get undefine function. pls help, Here is the code@ const handleUpdateCartQty, @handleRemoveFromCart and @handleEmptyCart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';  
import { Products, Navbar, Cart } from './Components';

  const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
    
    setProducts(data);
  }

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve())
  }
    const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
      const { cart } = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

      setCart(cart);

      const handleUpdateCartQty = async (productId, quantity) => {
        const { cart } = await commerce.cart.update(productId, { quantity });

        setCart(cart);
      }

      const handleRemoveFromCart = async (productId) => {
        const { cart } = await commerce.cart.remove(productId);

        setCart(cart);
      }

      const handleEmptyCart = async () => {
        const { cart } = await commerce.cart.empty();

        setCart(cart);
      }

    }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);


  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
          <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
           <Switch>  
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart
              cart={cart} 
              handleUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} 
              handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} 
              handleEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
            /> 
          </Route>
           </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router> 
  )
}

export default App;

`
```

Comment: handleRemoveFromCart, handleUpdateCartQty, handleEmptyCart should be outside handleAddToCart right?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much @Albert

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleEmptyCart = async () => {
    const { cart } = await commerce.cart.empty();
    
    setCart(cart);
    fetchcart();
    window.location.reload(); // both can be used....
}
```